# Howto count a variable inside of innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How is it possible to count a variable inside of a innerHTML?

JS

```
var counter = 1;
counter++;
alert(counter);

$(".end").html('Test ' + counter+1 + ' Test');
```

HTML

```
<p class="end"></p>
```

In my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38wkpy9n/1/) example, it works for alert example, but not in the innerHTML element. Why? How is it getting work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you are doing string concatenation.

Current evaluation

```
'Test ' + counter+1 + ' Test'
'Test 2' +1 + ' Test'
'Test 21' + ' Test'
'Test 21 Test'
```

You should wrap your calcualtion insde `()`

```
$(".end").html('Test ' + (counter+1) + ' Test');
```

When you add `()` that takes higher precedence and calculates first in the expression.

Current evaluation

```
'Test ' + (counter+1) + ' Test'
'Test ' + 3 + ' Test'
'Test 3' + ' Test'
'Test 3 Test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not adding.Just act like string.Add some `()` .Then it was added .try this `$(".end").html('Test ' +(counter + 1) + ' Test');`

```js
var counter = 1;
counter++;
alert(counter);

$(".end").html('Test ' +(counter + 1) + ' Test');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="end"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because initially `Test + counter` this converts counter int 2 to string hence addition happens as string try wrapping those in brackets as (counter + 1)

```
$(".end").html('Test ' + (counter+1) + ' Test');
```

Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38wkpy9n/2/)

For more info regarding the `+` operator see this [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Brackets, and it will work :

```
var counter = 1;
counter++;
alert(counter);

$(".end").html('Test ' + (counter+1) + ' Test');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add brackets to your code [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38wkpy9n/3/). 
Like this

```
$(".end").html('Test ' +( counter + 1 )+ ' Test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` for math calculation other wise its only string concatenation.

```js
var counter = 1;
counter++;
alert(counter);

$(".end").html('Test ' + parseInt(counter+1) + ' Test');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="end"></p>
```

Comment: Its better to use for calculation.

Comment: Better in which aspect ?