# Add a number to .height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this simple Jquery with the aim of setting the height of .button to that of its sibling.

```
$('.button').height($('.sibling').height());
```

the actual height of .sibling is 48px (24px + 24px padding, top and bottom).

However the returned height of .sibling excludes the padding, setting .button to 24px, not 48px.

I tried

```
$('.button').height($('.sibling').height() + "24" );
```

but that returns `2412px`

What is the proper way to do this? I see either change the original to somehow tell it to grab  height plus padding, otherwise how does one do proper math in Jquery in this case?

Comment: $('.sibling').height() + "12" it is concat operation of string. not adding numbers.. try with $('.sibling').height() + 12

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto count a variable inside of innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448284/howto-count-a-variable-inside-of-innerhtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the height including padding border etc you can use [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/)

`$('.button').height($('.sibling').outerHeight());`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are mixing **math** operation with **concatenation**.

Try seperating them like this:

```
var newHeight = $('.sibling').height() + 12;
$('.button').css('height', newHeight + 'px');
```

Or:

```
var newHeight = $('.sibling').height() + 12;
$('.button').height(newHeight);
```

Comment: The `height()` method accepts a number, so you don't need to append `px`

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing addition by doing following.

```
 $('.button').height($('.sibling').height() + "12" );
```

But you're concatenating an `integer` with a `string`

```
 $('.button').height($('.sibling').height() + 12 );
```

This is the right way of doing addition. Hope it helps.